# Alternative for HBase to store and query small files

Tags: database, c++, sqlite, hadoop, distributed

I'm using Hadoop on my system to store my files (each file is very large: ~4GB). I also have small sqlite3 db files (~50MB) and I would like to store them (somewhere - I don't have shared storage) and to allow access to those db files via any server on my environment.

I thought of using HBase to store my small data instead of sqlite3 db and later to use the HBase capabilities to run query on the data. I know the HBase is built for big files, **so I wonder if there is another solution which stores small files on multiple servers using hadoop.**

The solution must support:

- c/cpp api
- distributed storage / allow access from any server
- open source

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to store files, or to have a DB you can query? If you want to store files, why do you need software rather than the OS facilities on whatever machines you're targeting?

Comment: Part of the system stores files. The other part (the one I talked about) needs to store db files with the ability to query on those db files.